# how to display background image one every my selected tab with scroll in android

Tags: android, tabs, tabview

I am new to android ,first sorry for my bad English I am create tabs using google library similar to whats app tab views,

mainactivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




 Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"ALL","Women"};
    int Numboftabs =2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

SlideTabLayout

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

/**
 * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
 * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
 */
public interface TabColorizer {

    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;
private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Disable the Scroll Bar
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 *
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
 * similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}

public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
    mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
}


public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}


public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}



public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
  //  textView.setAllCaps(true);

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }

        tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
        tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
    }
}

public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
    mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

SlidingTabStrip

class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

```
private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

private int mSelectedPosition;
private float mSelectionOffset;

private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
    final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

    mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

    mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

    mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

    mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
}

void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
    mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
    invalidate();
}

void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
            ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : mDefaultTabColorizer;

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }

            // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
}

private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
    return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}


private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}

private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
    private int[] mIndicatorColors;

    @Override
    public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
    }

    void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mIndicatorColors = colors;
    }
}
```

}

here my XML files

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />


<com.example.onlinekart.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/primary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

tool_bar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

tab image between tab and app bar with scrolling effect like bellow image any one help me how to change my current tab to like bellow image model please suggest me i struck over 4 days i search loat of tutorials and google also  i m not found  fund any solution for this please any one help me

[image: my current tabview like this how to covert it]
here sample image i need like this 
[image: i need like this]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get what you mean. here is my solution:

1. set the tabs background as transparent,
2. add an `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager` using `ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()` in your activity. do not use `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()` because it will override the listener you set in your `TabColorizer`.
3. in the onPageSelected(), set background of the activity top view to the images you desire. it maybe more easy to use an `ImageView` with layout width and height both set to match_parent as the "background", since it is convenient to use `ImageView.ScaleType` to control the display.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bkg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_default_bkg_img"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />

        <com.example.onlinekart.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity layout xml

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final ImageView bkg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bkg);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            bkg.setBackgroundResource(R.id.your_bkg_img);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // if you want some fade in / fade out anim, you may want the values provided here
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

code about ViewPager in your activity.

wish this would help.

Comment: when i scroll my tab my app wash @Lyux

Comment: what's the exception log looks like?